# Should I sharpen or replace my table saw blade?

Tags: table-saw, sharpening

I got my table saw second hand several years ago.  It came with a general purpose blade which has served me well without cleaning or sharpening until recently.  I made what I now realize is a mistake in trying to rip some primed lumber.  The blade now binds and the saw stalls, even after cleaning it carefully.  Did I ruin the blade?  I can't really complain if the time has come to replace it.  Are sharpening services economical?  I can buy a new blade for $10-30 and I imagine sharpening isn't cheap.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I have cut painted and varnished wood a thousand times. Do you think it's binding because the blade has a sticky coating on it, or because it's gotten dull?

Comment: If he has been using the table saw for several years and it was used before that the blade is probably dull as can be. In any case a dull blade can be very dangerous to use.

Comment: Before this project, the last thing I did with my saw was cut some maple and I had no problem.  Now it gets bogged down cutting this primed pine.  I may be seeing a pattern where none exists but it seems to me that the primed wood significantly dulled or gummed up the blade.  Also, I got a cheap new blade for another project and swapped it in and it quickly bogged down, too.

Comment: Look carefully at the blade or take it off and lay it flat on a table. Is it warped?  I don’t cut wood often, but was having trouble and my neighbor happened along, in about 15 seconds he diagnosed my problem as a warped blade— similar symptoms to yours...

Comment: Chris, questions about costs are considered off-topic.  For more info, check out the help center https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: If you have any question about the blade replace with a new good quality blade.  This primed wood may have a lot of stress in it.  That type of lumber will bind and twist when it is cut; giving an impression something is wrong with the blade.

Comment: I'd dispute your pricing comparison. A good blade is probably $40-80 and sharpening is about $15 at my local hardware store. Then there's the waste factor. Consider the energy and pollution in creating new blades. #wreckedplanet

Comment: @virtualxtc, I took the question to be more about whether the primed lumber had somehow compromised the blade, but your point is taken.

Comment: @isherwood, yes, that was my question.  Not just economics but some feedback on what the primed wood may have done to the blade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably more economical to replace blades than sharpen them in your case. Sending blades out to be sharpened makes more sense for higher cost blades. Forrest's, for example, start around $100 so paying $30 to have them sharpened is quite a big savings over replacement. High quality melamine blades and stacked dados are even further into nosebleed pricing.